# Android: Opened Facebook page doesn't contain "LIKE" button

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-page

I'm developping an Android app and i want to put a button in order to let users go to Facebook page of the App.

i'm using the script below, which works fine :

```
public String getFacebookPageURL() {
    PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager();
    try {
        int versionCode = packageManager.getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0).versionCode;
        if (versionCode >= 3002850) { //newer versions of fb app
            return "fb://facewebmodal/f?href=" + getString(R.string.link_facebook);
        } else { //older versions of fb app
            return "fb://page/" + getString(R.string.ID_facebook);
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return getString(R.string.link_facebook); //normal web url
    }
}
```

The intent:

```
Intent facebookIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String facebookUrl = getFacebookPageURL();
facebookIntent.setData(Uri.parse(facebookUrl));
startActivity(facebookIntent);
```

The Facebook page is opened, but it doesn't contain the "LIKE" button as in the home page.

only the timeline/publications from the page.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you found solution?

Comment: No i have not found any solution.